# How to get idtoken from Android and post to server backend node.js

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, google-oauth

I've been trying to send the idToken gotten from an android app using google sign in to a server.But i haven't gotten any result.I've followed the documentation but to no avail.

On the logcat i get : `Unable to POST to http://localhost:5000/auth/google`

Explanation or example on how to solve this problem would be great.

I'm storing my data in **mongodb**.

Docs : [Add Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)

Docs : [Authenticate with server backend](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)

> Constants :

- url : http://localhost:5000
- client_id : *****gmun****qv2vl55h7k.apps.googleusercontent.com
- client_secret : ***MI3k17NCiHBj_elXt
- redirect_url : http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback

> Android Part :

**activity_auth.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.AuthActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.84000003" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Auth Activity.kt**

```kotlin
class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private var signIn = 9001
    private val tag = "AuthActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso)
        sign_in_button.setOnClickListener {
            signIn()
        }
    }

    private fun signIn(){
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, signIn)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == signIn){
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            //add silent sign in later on
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask : Task<GoogleSignInAccount>){
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            val idToken = account?.idToken

            //send id token to server and validate
            ConnectURLTask().execute(idToken)

            onLoggedIn(account)
        }
        catch (e : ApiException){
            Log.w(tag, "sign in failed , code : " + e. statusCode)
            onLoggedIn(null)
        }
    }

    private fun onLoggedIn(account: GoogleSignInAccount?){
        if (account != null){
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this@AuthActivity, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private class ConnectURLTask : AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {

        val tag = "Authentication"

        override fun doInBackground(vararg strings: String?): Void? {
            val httpClient: HttpClient = DefaultHttpClient()
            val httpPost = HttpPost("http://localhost:5000/auth/google")
            try {
                val nameValuePairs: MutableList<NameValuePair> = ArrayList(1)
                nameValuePairs.add(BasicNameValuePair("idToken", strings[0]))
                httpPost.entity = UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)
                val response: HttpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost)
                val statusCode = response.statusLine.statusCode
                val responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.entity)
                Log.i(tag, "Signed in as: $responseBody")
            } catch (e: ClientProtocolException) {
                Log.e(tag, "Error sending ID token to backend.", e)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(tag, "Error sending ID token to backend.", e)
            }
            return null
        }
    }
    
}
```

> Node

**User.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    googleId : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const User = require('./models/User');

//Connect to DB
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    () => console.log('Connected!')
);

const client = new OAuth2Client(
    process.env.client_id,
    process.env.client_secret,
    process.env.redirect_url
);

app.post('/auth/google', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Evaluating  post');
    const { idToken } = req.body;
    verify(idToken).catch(console.error);
});

//Verify Token method
async function verify(token) {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: token,
        audience: keystore.client_id
    });
    const payload = await ticket.getPayload();
    const userid = await payload['sub'];
    console.log(userid);
    User.findOne({ googleId: userid }).then(existingUser => {
        if (!existingUser) {
            new User({ googleId: userid }).save();
        }
    });
}

//Port Listener
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated...Thanks

Comment: Where's the client code that sends `idToken` to the server? And you should give more details on the problem you're having. Is the server not receiving the request at all, or is there a request but no idToken, etc.

Comment: @huytc thanks for your suggestion i've updated the question

Comment: Do you see anything logged on the server? Also, I think you can put a breakpoint in the `doInBackground` function and run in debug mode to see where it went wrong.